# OnClick of Button more views should be added at runtime in the layout, but I am not able ot do that

Tags: android, button, view, click

I want to add views on click of button. My screen has a text view and an edit text and a "Add More" button. on the click of button another set of text view and edit text should get appended to the screen. I am also planning to add scroll view once the my screen grows longer. 
My Code snippet is as follows

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        text.setText("hello how are you?");  //this is just an example, I may want to add lot more here.
    linearLayout.addView(text);  
    setContentView(linearLayout);  
        }
```

I know I am missing something very basic but I do not know what is that. :(
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to initialize each TextView with a reference to the context. So, in your onClick, given that it is in MyActivity.java:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  TextView text = new TextView(this);
  text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT); // Or what you decide
  text.setText("Your text");
  linearLayout.addView(text);
}
```

Second, given that you have a call to setContentView in onCreate which also adds your linearlayout to the view, you do not need to call setContentView(linearLayout) each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you should first create a new `TextView` and `EditText` add it to the `linearLayout` using `linearLayout.addView()`. No need to call `setContentView()` you probably already added it.

Comment: yes you are right setContentView() is not really needed to be add. I did not know that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

This One help you

In your XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myMainRelativeLayout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
    android:text="Add Button" />
```

And your Java file Like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

Button btnAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAdd) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myMainRelativeLayout);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(1234);
        btn.setText("Add Button Runtime");
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        rl.addView(btn);
    }
    if(v.getId() == 1234)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is Your New Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

This one just example you can add any view like this